# AnkhSVN Exception error (branching solution)

Tags: svn, ankhsvn, httpd.conf

I always get the error message below whenever I try to branch solution using AnkhSVN which is integrated in Visual Studio 2005:

SharpSvn.SvnReposito​ryIOException: 
Repository moved permanently to 'http://'; please relocate 
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientAr​gs.HandleResult(SvnC​lientContext client, SvnException error) 
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientAr​gs.HandleResult(SvnC​lientContext client, svn_error_t* error) 
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.R​emoteCopy[TSvnTarget​](ICollection`1 sourceTargets, Uri toUri, SvnCopyArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.R​emoteCopy(SvnTarget sourceTarget, Uri toUri, SvnCopyArgs args) 
   at Ankh.Commands.Branch​SolutionCommand.<​>c__DisplayClass4​.b_​_0(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs ee) 
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerS​ervice.ProgressRunne​r.Run(Object arg)

ankh-version=2.1.7362.250 
command=SolutionBranch 
svn-version=1.6.5 
sharpsvn-version=1.6​005.1351.39149 
vs-version=8.0.50727.42 
os-version=5.1.2600.196608

How can I be able to use branching in AnkhSVN?  How would I know the network protocol used in our Subversion server?  It seems that http was used as the protocol.  I also don't know the subversion repository URL used to create our subversion server since our admin is unavailable.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's your repository URL? http://foo/, http://foo/repos/ or http://foo/svn/repos/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this thread](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=582&dsMessageId=341347) at the AnkhSvn mailinglist. A user there has what seems to be the same problem. Perhaps the solution provided there can help you?